# Trying to embed another intranet site in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I am trying to build a react application where in I have created a menu of "Help". In Help, I am putting iFrame code to show intranet site, confluence pages, and show documents and videos. Problem is that confluence page also has header and my app also has its own. Is there any way to pick selected area of another web app in my react app.

```
<div>
           <Iframe url="https://community.intranet.com/community/pages/home"
            width="100%"
            height="450px"
            id="myId"
            className="myClassname"
            display="initial"
            position="relative"/>

          </div>
```

Comment: Why exactly do you mean by "pick selected area"? Do you want to scroll down to the part where the header is no longer visible?

Comment: If you have a component from another location, you will need to import it into your react file first using something like: ```import Iframe from "./src/Iframe``` before you can use it.

Comment: Yes @ŁukaszKarczewski I dont want to show another header that will let them navigate to repository of another project

Comment: @RahulPillai that is actually a product called confluence I cannot get hold of source

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css:

```
        <div style={{ marginTop: -50 }}> //whatever is the height of the confluence page header
          <Iframe
            url="https://community.intranet.com/community/pages/home"
            width="100%"
            height="450px"
            id="myId"
            className="myClassname"
            display="initial"
            position="relative"
          />
        </div>
```

This is a workaround solution in case if you dont find any other.but it works,tested.

Comment: Sorry @d-saurabh it did not work. Even it went on top of my menus

Comment: Its because of the natural stacking order on webpage.I think you have not set the "position" of your div the one contains "menus". Just give position to menus div its should work fine